# Find $\frac{BF}{FC}$ in terms of $b,c$

Tags: geometry

If $AD$ is the bisector of angle $BAC$ and $E$ is the reflection of $D$ to point $M$(midpoint of $BC$).We construct point $F$  such that angles $BAF=EAC$.Then find $\frac{BF}{FC}$ in terms of $b,c$.

[image]

**My attempt**:We have:

$\frac{BF}{FC}=\frac{AB}{AC}*\frac{\sin BAF}{\sin CAF}$

But then what?

Comment: What are $b$ and $c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the bisector theorem $BD=\frac{c}{b+c}a$ and $CD=\frac{b}{b+c}a$.
 
Since $BM=CM=\frac{1}{2}a$, $BE=\frac{b}{b+c}a$ and  $CE=\frac{c}{b+c}a.$
If $\widehat{BAF}=\widehat{EAC}$, the lines $AE$ and $AF$ have to be symmetric with respect to $AD$.
The trilinear coordinates of $E$ are $[0,c^2,b^2]$, hence the trilinear coordinates of $F$ are $[0,b^2,c^2]$ and
$$\frac{BF}{FC}=\frac{c^2/b}{b^2/c}=\color{red}{\frac{c^3}{b^3}}.$$

[image]

Comment: How did you conclude the last line?I mean trilinear coordinates of $F$.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: since $AE$ and $AF$ are symmetric with respect to the bisector from $A$, in order to get the trilinear coordinates of $F$ from the trilinear coordinates of $E$ (or the converse) it is enough to exchange the second and the third trilinear coordinates.

Comment: I understand that part but I don't know why.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: it follows from the definition of trilinear coordinates and the fact that $\widehat{BAF}=\widehat{EAC}$.